# JSON in localforage, efficient way to update property values (Binarysearch, etc.)?

Tags: javascript, json, local-storage

I would like to come straight to the point and show you my sample data, which is around the average of 180.000 lines from a .csv file, so a lot of lines. I am reading in the .csv with [papaparse](https://www.papaparse.com/). Then I am saving the data as array of objects, which looks like this:
[image]

I just used this picture as you can also see all the properties my objects have or should have. The data is from [Media Transperency Data](https://www.rtr.at/de/m/Medientransparenz), which is open source and shows the payments between institiutions.

The array of objects is saved by using the [localforage](https://github.com/localForage/localForage) technology, which is basically an IndexedDB or WebSQL with localstorage like API. So I save the data never on a sever! Only in the client!

**The Question:**
So my question is now, the user can add the `sourceHash` and/or `targetHash` attributes in a client interface. So for example assume the user loaded the "Energie Steiermark Kunden GmbH" object and now adds the `sourceHash` -- "company" to it. So basically a tag. This is already reflected in the client and shown, however I need to get this also in the localforage and therefore rewrite the initial array of objects. So I would need to search for every object in my huge 180.000 lines array that has the name "Energie Steiermark Kunden GmbH", as there can be multiple and set the property `sourceHash` to "company". Then save it again in the localforage.

The first question would be how to do this most efficient? I can get the data out of localforage by using the following method and set it respectively.

**Get:**

`localforage.getItem('data').then((value) => {
  ...
});`

**Set:**

`localforage.setItem('data', dataObject);`

However, the question is how do I do this most efficiently? I mean if the `sourceNode` only starts with "E" for example we don't need to search all `sourceNode`'s. The same goes of course for the `targetNode`.

Thank you in advance!

**UPDATE:**
Thanks for the answeres already! And how would you do it the most efficient way in Javascript? I mean is it possible to do it in few lines. If we assume I have for example the current sourceHash "company" and want to assign it to every node starting with "Energie Steiermark Kunden GmbH" that appear across all timeNode's. It could be 20151, 20152, 20153, 20154 and so on...

Comment: *if the sourceNode only starts with "E" for example we don't need to search all sourceNode's.* Really? How would you know their sourceNode doesn't start with an E if you don't do a lookup on them?

Comment: Well I described it bad I think. If the source nodes name is "Energie Steiermark Kunden GmbH" we don't have to search further down, because the source node can appear in various quarters, e.g. 2016/1 2016/2 and so on but we only need to search for this specific node.

Answer (score 0):

Localforage is only a `localStorage`/`sessionStorage`-like wrapper over the actual storage engine, and so it only offers you the key-value capabilities of `localStorage`. In short, there's no more efficient way to do this for arbitrary queries.

This sounds more like a case for IndexedDB, as you can define search indexes over the data, for instance for `sourceNode`s, and do more efficient queries that way.

Comment: localforage only falls back to localStorage when neither IndexedDB nor WebSQL are available...

Comment: Yes, but it only provides the localStorage-like key-value API no matter what backend it uses.

Comment: Well the main difference ia that value doesn't have to be a string